# Watching changes in Mac OS X

Tags: security, macos, notifications

Im working in a security app for Mac OS X and i need to watch any activities in the computer like USB, firewire, network interfaces, audio IO, disc drives and the sudden motion sensor. I found out  out how to detect USB/Discs devices using the DiskArbitration framework, ideas of how to detect non-storage USB/firewire devices and all other things listed above are very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question really doesn't have anything to do with Objective-C or Cocoa, so I removed those tags. Indeed, if you're trying to write something that's really secure in MacOS X, you're probably not doing it in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, I need those watchers only for physical security, not a big deal

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm using the system_profiler command and getting the output using the NSTask object, system_profiler is solving my problem for now.